# Spring CrudRepository delete() does nothing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

During a Unit test i'm trying to delete an entry from my database via Spring's CrudRepository, but it seems like nothing is happening.

The entity:

```java
@Entity @Table(name = "FACTION")
public class Faction implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "int", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

The repository:

```java
public interface FactionDao extends CrudRepository<Faction, Integer>
{

}
```

My test class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@Sql({ "/delete-testData.sql", "/insert-testData.sql" })
public class TestFactionDao
{
    @Autowired
    private FactionDao dao;

    @Test
    public void testDelete()
    {
        System.out.println(this.dao.findOne(1));
        this.dao.delete(1);
        System.out.println(this.dao.findOne(1));
    }
}
```

Spring configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Config.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config
{
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource pDataSource)
    {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(pDataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource pDataSource)
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter tJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        tJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        tJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        tJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean tEntityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        tEntityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(tJpaVendorAdapter);
        tEntityManagerFactory.setDataSource(pDataSource);
        tEntityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(Config.class.getPackage().getName());
        return tEntityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```

The sql scripts:

```
-- delete-testData.sql

delete from FACTION;

-- insert-testData.sql

insert into FACTION (ID) values
(1);
```

Below is the console output during the test case. As you can see, no delete operation is executed and i can still read the entity i just deleted:

```
Hibernate: create table FACTION (ID int generated by default as identity, primary key (ID))
Hibernate: select faction0_.ID as ID1_3_0_ from FACTION faction0_ where faction0_.ID=?
de.iavra.data.Faction@1b97f47
Hibernate: select faction0_.ID as ID1_3_0_ from FACTION faction0_ where faction0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select faction0_.ID as ID1_3_0_ from FACTION faction0_ where faction0_.ID=?
de.iavra.data.Faction@17b8fa4
```

I tried annoting my test method with @Rollback(false), but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Calling flush() on the dao throws an exception saying there are no pending updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your code, and the solution is to change transactionManager type from PlatformTransactionManager to JpaTransactionManager. (I think maybe PlatformTransactionManager only commit the delete when the function ends.)

So the code is:

Config.java

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource pDataSource) {
     HibernateJpaVendorAdapter tJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
     ...
```

Comment: That did it. I'm guessing the error wouldn't have occured in production, because i can use container managed transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You must add transaction for `update` and `delete` operations.

```
public class FactionService {
    @Autowired
    private FactionDao dao;

    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id){
        dao.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i add @Transactional to the method (either the spring or persistence one) the delete fails with "org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class de.iavra.data.Faction entity with id 1 exists!". It doesn't seem to find the test data i inserted before the method.

I assumed that Spring Data handles transactions inside the repository, so i don't have to add Transactional to my methods.